# Android CTS code about storage throughput calculation

Tags: java, android, ram, throughput, cts

I need to calculate the storage throughput in my Android device, and I found source code about calculating storage sequential RW throughput in Android CTS.

[FileUtil.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/a803685/suite/cts/deviceTests/filesystemperf/src/com/android/cts/filesystemperf/FileUtil.java)

```
public static long getFileSizeExceedingMemory(Context context, int bufferSize) {
    long freeDisk = SystemUtil.getFreeDiskSize(context);
    long memSize = SystemUtil.getTotalMemory(context);
    long diskSizeTarget = (2 * memSize / bufferSize) * bufferSize;
    final long minimumDiskSize = (512L * 1024L * 1024L / bufferSize) * bufferSize;
    final long reservedDiskSize = (50L * 1024L * 1024L / bufferSize) * bufferSize;
    if ( diskSizeTarget < minimumDiskSize ) {
        diskSizeTarget = minimumDiskSize;
    }
    if (diskSizeTarget > freeDisk) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Free disk size " + freeDisk + " too small");
        return 0;
    }
    if ((freeDisk - diskSizeTarget) < reservedDiskSize) {
        diskSizeTarget -= reservedDiskSize;
    }
    return diskSizeTarget;
}
```

This function is about to create a file from RAM to storage(write) and then read back.

I was just wondering:

```
long diskSizeTarget = (2 * memSize / bufferSize) * bufferSize;
```

Why they need to prepare a file which is around double ram size?

I've ever tried file size which is a half of ram size (my device ram size=2GB), and the write throughput looks normal but read throughput is too fast(around 200MB/s).

But the result looks fine when I use around 4GB file(double ram size) and 2GB.

(The buffersize parameters are 10MB for read and write)

Here are the read and write codes:

[SequentialRWTest.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/filesystem/src/android/filesystem/cts/SequentialRWTest.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F)

```
public void testSingleSequentialRead() throws Exception {
    final long fileSize = FileUtil.getFileSizeExceedingMemory(getContext(), BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (fileSize == 0) { // not enough space, give up
        return;
    }
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final File file = FileUtil.createNewFilledFile(getContext(),
            DIR_SEQ_RD, fileSize);
    long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String streamName = "test_single_sequential_read";
    DeviceReportLog report = new DeviceReportLog(REPORT_LOG_NAME, streamName);
    report.addValue("file_size", fileSize, ResultType.NEUTRAL, ResultUnit.NONE);
    report.addValue("write_throughput",
            Stat.calcRatePerSec((double)fileSize / 1024 / 1024, finish - start),
            ResultType.HIGHER_BETTER, ResultUnit.MBPS);
    final int NUMBER_READ = 10;
    final byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    double[] times = MeasureTime.measure(NUMBER_READ, new MeasureRun() {
        @Override
        public void run(int i) throws IOException {
            final FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            long read = 0;
            while (read < fileSize) {
                in.read(data);
                read += BUFFER_SIZE;
            }
            in.close();
        }
    });
    double[] mbps = Stat.calcRatePerSecArray((double)fileSize / 1024 / 1024, times);
    report.addValues("read_throughput", mbps, ResultType.HIGHER_BETTER, ResultUnit.MBPS);
    Stat.StatResult stat = Stat.getStat(mbps);
    report.setSummary("read_throughput_average", stat.mAverage, ResultType.HIGHER_BETTER,
            ResultUnit.MBPS);
    report.submit(getInstrumentation());
}
```

And createNewFilledFile function in FileUtil.java

```
public static File createNewFilledFile(Context context, String dirName, long length)
        throws IOException {
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    File file = createNewFile(context, dirName);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] data = generateRandomData(BUFFER_SIZE);
    long written = 0;
    while (written < length) {
        out.write(data);
        written += BUFFER_SIZE;
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    return file;
}
```

Comment: Presumably because although you say "_This function is about to create a file to read and write from RAM to storage._" it's actually going to _write_ the file first, then _read_ it back. If the file is small enough, a copy may still be in RAM so it might never read directly from storage.  If the file twice the size of RAM, the start of the file will have been overwritten, so the read will have to come directly from storage.

Comment: Thank you, TripeHound. Yes  it's write(create file) first and then read. I've already edited this post, thanks again.

Comment: I also assumed what you talked about. But is this possible that my RAM will keep whole file size (for example,1G) after writing file? Because we only generate 10MB in RAM first and then put the same 10MB to storage each time . I am new in this field,please correct me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've not studied the code in detail, but the 10MB looks like the size of the "chunk" being read or written at a time. If the total size written is less than half available RAM, it's possible that the file being written will remain in the cache (depending what else needs it). Making t he total size twice the size of RAM guarantees that nothing remains in the cache so all reads have to come from storage.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your kindly help, ThripeHound.